Can a stationary process have "gaps"?
A process $\{X_t\}$ is said to be strictly stationary if
$$
F_X\left(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_n}\right) = F_X\left(X_{t_{1}+\tau},...,X_{t_n+\tau}\right)
$$
holds for all points in time $t_1,...,t_n\in \mathbb{R}$, all lags $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$, and where $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function.
For example, it holds that $F_X(X_4,X_5,X_6)=F_X(X_{104},X_{105},X_{106})$, and it also holds that $F_X(X_{22}) = F_X(X_{10000})$.
Question: Can a stationary process have "gaps" in $F_X$, e.g., does it also hold that $F_X(X_1,X_3)=F_X(X_{101},X_{103})$?
I was thinking that this should hold, since in a weakly stationary process, the covariance $\text{Cov}(X_1,X_3)$ is equal to $\text{Cov}(X_{101},X_{103})$, and a stationary process is also weakly stationary (given finite mean and covariance). But I am not sure.

$P(X_1 \in A_1, X_3 \in A_3)=P(X_1 \in A_1,X_2 \in \mathbb R, X_3 \in A_3)=P(X_{101} \in A_{1},X_{102} \in \mathbb R, X_{103} \in A_3)=P(X_{101} \in A_{1}, X_{103} \in A_3)$.
